# Reloading just one model using RSVP in Ember

Tags: ember.js

To load many data models into a route on the model hook you need to use RSVP so I'm doing this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend( {
  queryParams: {
    color: {
      refreshModel: true,
    },
  },

  model( params ) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash( {
      cars: this.store.query( "car", params ),
      stats: this.store.findRecord( "shop", params.shopId ),
    } );
  },

  actions: {
    filterByColor( color ) {
      if ( color !== -1 ) {
        this.transitionTo( { queryParams: { color } } );
      }

      else {
        this.transitionTo( { queryParams: { color: undefined } } );
      }
    },
  },
} );
```

The problem comes in that `stats` is always going to be the same but using queryParams I will change the `cars` list.

The action (triggered from a button) will transition to the same page changing the queryParams, which will call the model hook (as intended) but it will reload both models, `cars` and `stats`, when I'm only interested in refreshing `cars`.

Is there a way, with or without RSVP, to load both models on entry but only update one of them when queryParams change?

Answer (score 1):

You can use setupcontroller hook in you route file. setupController hook always called when you transistion to route. Whenever you change queryParams, model hook called.
you can pass "stats" model into controller by using setupController hook. like that

Modelhook should be like that

```
model( params ) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash( {
      cars: this.store.query( "car", params ),
      stats:params.shopId 
    } );
  },

     setupController: function(controller, model) {
      controller.set('cars', model.cars );
      controller.set('stats',this.store.findRecord( "shop", model.shopId ));
    }
```

after these changes you have to use linkto transition with `.id` and also use `cars` `stats` model in controller or template. you cannot use `model.cars` or `model.stats` in controller or template. because we are passing cars and stats model in controller by setupcontroller hook.